# making EditText to show only two decimal places

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i want to show only two decimal places in my edit text, ofc i wanna show currency in edit text but limiting its value to 2 digits after decimal.

I have seen some solutions using regular expression but i don't wanna do that. I HAVE been told that java support some internal library functions that can do that. Any one can please give me hints or give me some efficient code for that.

Regards

```
amount.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);

         amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
         {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DecimalFormat formatVal = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                String formatted = formatVal.format(s);
                amount.setText(formatted);

            }
```

Comment: Have you thought about implementing some kind of 2 slot picker instead? Just an idea. Maybe a friendlier UX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use [`DecimalFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
String formatted = format.format(22.123);
editText.setText(formatted);
```

You will get result in `EditText` as `22.12`

Comment: can you please clarify, how to use it?

Comment: ok i have put this code in onTextChanged property. it is giving illegal argument exception. Any Idea?

Comment: Without seeing code how can I get an idea where you are getting exception?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that will limit the user while typing in the edit text.

```
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    final int maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint=2;
    final int maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint=2;

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(dest);
            builder.replace(dstart, dend, source
                    .subSequence(start, end).toString());
            if (!builder.toString().matches(
                    "(([1-9]{1})([0-9]{0,"+(maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint-1)+"})?)?(\\.[0-9]{0,"+maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint+"})?"

                    )) {
                if(source.length()==0)
                    return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
                return "";
            }

        return null;

    }
};

mEdittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

e.g., 12.22 so only 2 digits before and two digits after the decimal ponit will be allowed to be entered.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign `setKeyListener()` to your `EditText`.

```
myEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));
```

Returns a `DigitsKeyListener` that accepts the digits 0 through 9, plus the minus sign (only at the beginning) and/or decimal point (only one per field) if specified.

Answer (score 0):

> Input:

```
 mBinding.etPriceUpdate.setText = getString(R.string.txt_rupees) + " " + "%.2f".format(firstNum!!.toDouble() * secondNum.toDouble())
```

Output:

> ₹ 4567.54

This will format the floating-point number 1.23456 up to 2 decimal places because we have used two after the decimal point in formatting instruction %.2f, f is for floating-point number, which includes both double and float data type in Java. Don't try to use "d" for double here, because that is used to format integer and stands for decimal in formatting instruction. By the way, there is a catch here, format() method will also arbitrarily round the number. For example, if you want to format 1.99999 up-to 2 decimal places then it will return 2.0 rather then 1.99, as shown below.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. Also add more code that indicates where this fits in the question's code.