# How Edittext can accept only two numbers after decimal point

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I am trying to add only two numbers after a decimal point input in an `EditText`.

So I implemented a `TextWatcher` to check the `string` during input.

The function I am using below works amazing but has one major flaw. When you input any value,then you add a decimal point,delete that decimal point and proceed to add more values,only 3 values are accepted as input.

**Case example:** I input `300.` but then I realize I wanted to input `3001234567`, so I delete the decimal point `.` and proceed to add `1234567` to `300`, Only `123` will be accepted and the rest ignored.

How should i handle this? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

My code:

```
 price.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

     }

     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

     }

     public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
         if (arg0.length() > 0) {
             String str = price.getText().toString();
             price.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                         count--;
                         InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
                         fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(100);
                         price.setFilters(fArray);
                         //change the edittext's maximum length to 100.
                         //If we didn't change this the edittext's maximum length will
                         //be number of digits we previously entered.
                     }
                     return false;
                 }
             });
             char t = str.charAt(arg0.length() - 1);
             if (t == '.') {
                 count = 0;
             }
             if (count >= 0) {
                 if (count == 2) {
                     InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
                     fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(arg0.length());
                     price.setFilters(fArray);
                     //prevent the edittext from accessing digits
                     //by setting maximum length as total number of digits                               we typed till now.
                 }
                  count++;
              }
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [making EditText to show only two decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323618/making-edittext-to-show-only-two-decimal-places)

Comment: You probably shouldn't be too hasty to mark duplicates without reviewing both cases.

Comment: I reviewed both. And that use can be totally applied here if you remove this long `if-else` block.

Comment: `two numbers` ? You mean `two digits` ?

Comment: @greenapps yes digits

Comment: @Rohit5k2 have you tried, what you linked to? I think it is not a sufficient answer, given in the linked answer. It is incomplete and not working directly. Also this scenario is a bit more complex. I would not mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @AlbAtNf yes I agree, I tried the accepted answer but didn't work out

Comment: Then edit the subject and the text of your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             String input = s.toString();
            if(input.contains(".") && s.charAt(s.length()-1) != '.'){
                if(input.indexOf(".") + 3 <= input.length()-1){
                    String formatted = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(".") + 3);
                    editReceiver.setText(formatted);
                    editReceiver.setSelection(formatted.length());
                }
            }else if(input.contains(",") && s.charAt(s.length()-1) != ','){
                if(input.indexOf(",") + 3 <= input.length()-1){
                    String formatted = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(",") + 3);
                    editReceiver.setText(formatted);
                    editReceiver.setSelection(formatted.length());
                }
            }
        }
```

Please note, german decimals are , seperated instead of . seperated
You can remove that else part, if it is not needed.

Comment: Another problem, how do i limit to only one decimal point input?

Comment: Nevermind i did it using `mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html and other such classes give you the option of dynamically getting the region and then using the "decimal point" and "thousands separator" as is appropriate "." and "," or "," and "." based on region. That way you don't have to hard code characters like you are here (more adaptable)